# Entity Framework add first row to database from a List?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

```
foreach (StockItem item in StockList)
{
    Master master = new Master();
    master.VoucherNo = BillNo;
    master.Voucher = "Sales";
    master.StockName = StockList[0].StockName;
    master.Quantity = StockList[0].Quantity;
    master.Unit = StockList[0].Unit;
    master.Price = StockList[0].UnitPrice;
    master.Amount = StockList[0].Amount;
    dbContext.AddToMasters(master);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
Sale sale = new Sale();
sale.InvoiceNo = BillNo;
sale.Date = BillDate;
sale.Party = Customer;
sale.Amount = (decimal)TotalAmount;
dbContext.AddToSales(sale);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This code add only the first row from `StockList` for all n times if there are n rows.

What wrongs with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over StockList, but you aren't actually using the iteration variable.

Everywhere that you use StockList[0], you should be using item.

Edit: Here is what your loop should look like:

```
foreach (StockItem item in StockList)
{
    Master master = new Master();
    master.VoucherNo = BillNo;
    master.Voucher = "Sales";
    master.StockName = item.StockName;
    master.Quantity = item.Quantity;
    master.Unit = item.Unit;
    master.Price = item.UnitPrice;
    master.Amount = item.Amount;
    dbContext.AddToMasters(master);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```